# Highlighting rows based on conditions in two columns using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like this:

```
S.No  Name  Year   Pay

 1      A   2004   100
 2      B   2005   200
 3      C   2004   75
```

Rows having Year = 2004 *and* Pay in {75, 200, 300} need to be highlighted. I'd like to use something like this:

```
$('tr').find('td:eq(2):contains(2004)')
  .parent()
    .find('td:eq(3)')
      .filter(function(){
        return parseInt($(this).text()) < 300;
      })
      .parent()
        .css('backgroundColor', '#E8E8E8');
```

In the above working jquery I need to replace the inner condition **< 300** with something like **in {75,200,300}**

Kindly help me in debugging this issue.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where the {75, 200, 300} is coming from given your question.  But if you're just checking to see if a value is in a list of other values then you could use the indexOf() method for javascript arrays.  [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4GyYk/)</kbd>

```
$('tr').filter(function() {
    var $this=$(this);
    // Search for 2004 and trim whitespace just in case in 3th column (year)
    if ($.trim($this.children('td').eq(2).text()) == "2004") {
        // Search for predefined values in 4th column and if found return true
        if ( ~['75', '200', '300'].indexOf( $.trim($this.children('td').eq(3).text()) ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}).css('backgroundColor', '#E8E8E8');
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a regex for that? In case

```
    $('tr').find('td:eq(2):contains(2004)').parent().find('td:eq(3)').filter(function(){
return parseInt($(this).text().match(/(75)|(200)|(300)/g));
}).parent().css('backgroundColor', '#E8E8E8');
```

I just did another way in the same fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/joeSaad/6jPs9/#base

Comment: Your '/75|200|300/' will match values like 1200 or 275.  You may need to match boundaries or start and end of string in order to actually achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: you are right, did it in a haste. thanks for your comment. I just corrected it.